# How to install Oracle DB 12c on Solaris 11.2?

Tags: oracle-12c

I downloaded file 1 and file 2 and extracted it in one folder called ORCLDB.
When I run ./runInstall as root from terminal it says

The user is root. Oracle universal installer cannot continue if the user is root

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is very thorough in this regard.

You need to follow the pre-install instructions for your platform. Create an oracle user, dba and oinstall group, change OS params etc.

All of the instructions for Solaris SPARC are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SSDQI/toc.htm#BABDAGHH).

Comment: I am a new learner...some of the literature could be hard for me to understand...

Comment: It explains in simple English. Read the documentation. Help is available for £50 an hour for personal tuition if FREE isn't enough

Comment: simple english, to you, but many other things of computer files and architecture which I have yet to learn...

Comment: The documentation is very clear. It has all of the commands you need to execute.

Comment: where the heck are the previous answers and talks